# c# Check pre-populated Checklistbox Items based on String or List of strings

Tags: c#, checklistbox

We have a c# Winforms project in Visual studio 2017.
When a form loads, it populates a checklistbox control with values from the settings.

By default all the items inside the checklistbox are unchecked.

With another button later on we get a string separated by commas for example (apple,oranges,kiwies)

What we want to do is if the item exists in the checklistbox compared with the string we get then to make it checked.

Anyone can help with this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check a item of a checkListBox with the `SetItemCheckState` method by using the index of the item inside `checkListBox.Items` .
You can check if a string exists in `checkListBox.Items` with the `IndexOf` method which returns the index of the item that matches the string. 
If `checkListBox.Items` contains the string the desired checkbox will be checked, if not `IndexOf` will return `-1` and no checking will be done. Here is an example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fruit = "apple, oranges, kiwies";
    string[] fruitArr = fruit.Split(',').Select(x=>x.Trim()).ToArray();
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var item in fruitArr)
    {
        index = checkedListBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList().IndexOf(item);

        if (index > -1)
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(index, CheckState.Checked);
        }
    }
}
```

Populating the `checkListBox` :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> fruitList = new List<string>() { "pineapple","banana","apple","oranges"  };
    foreach (var fruit in fruitList)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(fruit);
    }
}
```